# Change the certain text to upper case before ':'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiline of string, at the end of the line I have ':'. now I want to change the word of the whole line before ':' to upper case. how can I change this?

```
var temp= "Professional Endermologie Lipomassage Total Care at £65 (35 minutes)
Professional Endermologie LPG Cellulite Smoothing Treatment at £65 (35 minutes)
Professional Inch Loss Wrap at £80 (2 hours)
Thalgo Polynesia Spa Ritual at £120 (1.30 hours)
Laser Hair removal:";


var rsdata = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(":"));
var rsdata = temp.split(':')[0];
data = temp.replace(rsdata, rsdata.toUpperCase());
console.log(data);
```

Here the sample code i have use to change the particular text.

Comment: By multi line what do you mean? Word wrap in your editor doesnt make it multi line. Only `\n` does.

Comment: Hi sir., thanks for your replay. actually i want to change Laser Hair removal string only to the uppercase . for this what should i want to do ? this is my query sir.

Comment: This code can easily be turned into a runnable snippet.  Why haven't you done that?

Comment: Hello! can you just hardcode the capital letters in it instead of trying to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: no this is not a static one likewise this text I want to dynamically change the string to uppercase before the ': '. that is what I want

Answer (score 1):

Simple example, using Template Literals for multi-line string:

```
var text = `Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4 with colon: after colon`;

text = text.replace(/.+?:/, function(match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(text);
```